# spring cloud stream different concurrency setting for two different groups not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I have configured default concurrency setting and I have another group which needs different concurrency level, but the second one is defaulting concurrency to 1 regardless.
It was working fine with spring boot 1.5.4 and springCloudVersion Dalston.SR4.
Current versions are spring-boot 2.0.4 and springCloudVersion is Finchley.SR1 
I am using rabbitMQ.

`spring.cloud.stream.default.group=foo`
`spring.cloud.stream.default.consumer.concurrency=3`

I have another custom group

`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.customChannel.group=bar` 
`spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.customChannel.consumer.concurrency=5`

All channels in the group foo is 3. However the concurrency for customChannel is defaulting to 1. Has anyone faced similar issue with upgrades ?

Comment: It looks like it's not supported, https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1360

Comment: Concurrency is a common consumer property, where defaults are supported; that issue is about rabbit-specific defaults.

Answer (score 1):

There must be something else going on; this works fine for me:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(So52172152Application.Foo.class)
public class So52172152Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So52172152Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener("one")
    public void listen1(String in) {

    }


    @StreamListener("two")
    public void listen2(String in) {

    }

    @StreamListener("three")
    public void listen3(String in) {

    }

    public interface Foo {

        @Input
        MessageChannel one();

        @Input
        MessageChannel two();

        @Input
        MessageChannel three();

    }

}
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.default.group=foo
spring.cloud.stream.default.consumer.concurrency=3

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.three.group=bar
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.three.consumer.concurrency=5
```

And I see 3 consumers on each of the foo group queues and 5 on the bar group.

Comment: I found out my configuration was : `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.customChannel.consumer.concurrency = 5`       
  it works fine when `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.customChannel.consumer.concurrency = 5` .                I understood that Concurrency is common property for stream not rabbit specific.Edited my question.